# Magento 2: Which permission is needed to access `GET /V1/inventory/stock-source-links`?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, multi-source-inventory

I have the set of permissions: `Stores`, `Catalog`, `Customers`, `Stores`.

[image]

When I get the endpoint `GET /V1/inventory/stock-source-links` I'm receiving the exception:

```
The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.","parameters":{"resources":"Magento_InventoryApi::stock_source_link"}
```

Though, it works when I grant "all" permissions.

Which permission is needed to reach this endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to mark checked for source and stock and then check once in POSTman
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have `Inventory` section in the list of permissions. How to get it?

Comment: It should be available as already mentioned in https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/inventory/
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/modules/inventory/link-stocks-sources.html ..second link for rest api

Comment: Thank you! I've tried it for Magento 2.3.1, and it doesn't work. Though, for Magento 2.3.4 it works fine with `Source to Stock Assigning` permission set. So, it seem to be some Magento 2.3.1 bug

Comment: ok great ..may be issues with 2.3.1